# Adding military times to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I need to convert the word in object to a series of repeated records where the value in the object is replaced with hourly military format time triggers (no colon) starting at 7am and ending at 7pm.  Also I want increment the time by one minute for each successive object.  Retain all other values in the other columns (just repeat them), so the only value that’s changing is the time.

So the ANYTIME value in the persons object (John Doe) would look like:

•   0700
•   0800
•   0900
•   1000
•   1100
•   1200
•   1300
•   1400
•   1500
•   1600
•   1700
•   1800
•   1900

```js
const person = [{
    name: "John Doe",
    address: "1234 Driven St",
    id: "DF11111",
    time: "ANYTIME"
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    address: "555 Crank St",
    id: "HA22222",
    time: "ANYTIME"
  }
];

function array1() {
  var milTime = [700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900];

  if (person.time == "ANYTIME") {
    for (var e = 0; e < milTime.length; e++) {
      var newArray = milTime[e] + 1;
    }
  }
}

array1();
```

Comment: `var newArray = milTime[e] + 1;` ???? No clue what you are expecting, what is the final outcome when the code is done running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function array1(person) {
  var milTime = [700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900]
                .map(x=>(x+1+'').padStart(4,'0'));

  person.forEach(p => p.time = p.time=="ANYTIME" ? milTime.join` • ` : p.time )
}
```

```js
const person = [{
    name: "John Doe",
    address: "1234 Driven St",
    id: "DF11111",
    time: "ANYTIME"
  },
  {
    name: "Jane Doe",
    address: "555 Crank St",
    id: "HA22222",
    time: "ANYTIME"
  }
];

function array1(person) {
  var milTime = [700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900]
                .map(x=>(x+1+'').padStart(4,'0'));

  person.forEach(p => p.time = p.time=="ANYTIME" ? milTime.join` • ` : p.time )
}

array1(person);

console.log(person);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
   const persons = [{
        name: "John Doe",
        address: "1234 Driven St",
        id: "DF11111",
        time: "ANYTIME"
      },
      {
        name: "Jane Doe",
        address: "555 Crank St",
        id: "HA22222",
        time: "ANYTIME"
      }
    ];
    let increment = 1;
    function setTime() {
      var milTime = [700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900];
      persons.forEach(person => {
      if (person.time == "ANYTIME") {
        person.time = []
        milTime.forEach(time => {
          person.time.push(("0" + (time + increment)).substr(-4))
        })
      }
      increment++;
      })
    }

    setTime();
    console.log(persons)
```